# ECONNRESET error in Nodejs while calling API request

Tags: node.js, request, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I'm using NodeJS in my application, I'm trying to call API service to get the token from the server. While I'm making any request from the NodeJS file I'm getting "ECONNRESET" error. I've tried with some API , which reflects the same error. Below is my code

```
import request = require('request');

request('https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2', (err,result,body){
 console.log(body);
});
```

The above is my code which I've tried with sample API. When I'm trying to run this code I'm getting

```
Error: read ECONNRESET 
       at TLSwrap.onstreamread( interal/stream_base_common.js:207:27 {
       error: -4077,
       code: ECONNRESET,
       syscall: read
}
```

Comment: Do you have some proxy?

Comment: yes i've proxy in my npmrc file

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a proxy.  This error occurs when not able connecting to the server.

[Check your browser's proxy connection](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxycheck/ihdmjfbbjiddngjkejjndioplkkfmnoe?hl=en-GB) and
[Check your machine's proxy connection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-checker)